# Make the window title less chunky in big sur

Tags: big-sur

In Big Sur the window title bar looks too chunky in icon only mode. It looks like the bar was designed for "Icon + Text" but doesn't shrink when you remove the text.

Example:

Icon and Text:
[image]

Icon only:
[image]

Text only:
[image]

Is there a way to shrink the size of the title bar so that it doesn't look so chunky. So it looks more like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

good news, the chunky bars problem is being worked on:
here's [MEMiniMe](https://github.com/MacEnhance/MEMiniMe).

it needs macForge, and it isn't working on mac m1 yet as far as i know, but hopefully ..soon.. we'll have a solution for these horrible fat bars.

Comment: Maybe i misse something or this is an extreme example of blowing solutions out of the water with complicated stuff, see my answer which works fine for me on Intel Macs.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the MeMiniMe answer, i looked at the code and all it does is to use the undocumented "setToolbarStyle" function which is defined as normal in the Cocoa headers.

```
[toolbar setDisplayMode:NSToolbarDisplayModeIconOnly];
[window setToolbarStyle: NSWindowToolbarStyleUnifiedCompact];
```

Comment: And what files here need to be changed or added to?

Comment: In Swift, it would be as simple as `window.toolbarStyle = .unifiedCompact`

Answer (score 1):

`defaults` allows you to set some "hidden" settings for the window style. At the moment I only found one that allows you to go back to the old toolbar style with

```
defaults write -g NSWindowSupportsAutomaticInlineTitle -bool false
```

If there are other *NSWindow* setting in Big Sur then they may be listed on [macos-defaults.com](https://macos-defaults.com/) in the future.

Comment: That just makes it bigger.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty You are right - I was testing VMware and thought the title got smaller.

Comment: made it smaller for me after reboot

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to use the open source app [ThemeEngine](https://github.com/jslegendre/ThemeEngine) to edit `.car` files and tweak all the UI. The V.3 branch is for macOS Big Sur and later.

I tested it on Big Sur and an Apple M1 and, from what I can tell, every part of the theme is modifiable. colours, icons, traffic lights, size of the different UI elements, .etc.

A short feedback report can be found [here](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine/issues/67). This is screenshot of the app:
[image]

The downside is that SIP needs to be disabled, a few actions in Terminal are required and you must reboot to apply the modifications, each time. But it does work.